# Are you allowed to have templates that can never be instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

I vaguely recall a rule that states that variadic function templates have to be instantiable with more than just an empty pack. Do similar rules apply to templates in general?

For example:

```cpp
template <int N>
struct array {
    // when instantiated, always ill-formed
    // however, expression is dependent on N, so the compiler allows this
    int arr[N * 0];
};

template <int N>
void foo() {
    int arr[N * 0]; // same as above
}
```

Is the above code ill-formed, no diagnostic required, or is it well-formed? What if we defined a partial specialization for `array` so that it becomes impossible to instantiate the primary template?

```cpp
template <int N>
requires true
struct array<N> {};
```

Comment: I think you may be looking for https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1

Comment: At least for function templates there's an example in the standard library that must not be instanciated and will likely be implemented to result in a compiler error, if instanciated: [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Comment: There are two different concepts here: (in)valid instantiations and instantiations that always result in a compilation error. `std::declval` is an example of the latter.

Comment: @fabian we can't draw conclusions from `std::declval`. It's a magic function that can have special properties which templates normally don't have.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux does that paragraph apply to the `array` class template as a whole, or to the primary template individually? If it applies to it as a whole, then we could un-ifndr it with a partial specialization like in my question.

Comment: @JanSchultke My interpretation is that without the partial specialization, the code is ill-formed but adding any partial specialization that is legal the code becomes well-formed. Though I am not entirely confident, which is why I'm commenting and not posting an answer.

Comment: @fabian all entities in the standard library are special and can have magic properties given to them by the implementation, that you cannot achieve in user-defined code. For example, `malloc` returns memory which allows you to begin lifetimes implicitly by writing to it. There is no way to implement this property as a user. Also, cppreference isn't normative and basically useless in language-lawyer questions.

Comment: @JanSchultke `std::declval` doesn't require compiler magic. While cppreference isn't normative, can be contain counter-examples which can be useful when discussing language-lawyer questions. In this case, it provides an example of how `std::declval` could be implemented by the library without compiler support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the above code ill-formed, no diagnostic required, or is it well-formed? What if we defined a partial specialization for array so that it becomes impossible to instantiate the primary template?

Yes, it is IFNDR because of [[temp.res.general]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#8.1), assuming that you never try to instantiate the (primary) template (and otherwise it is ill-formed with a diagnostic required). Whether the partial specialization is present doesn't matter. It doesn't change anything about the fact that the (primary) template cannot be instantiated for any valid specialization.

The point of the rule was probably (I don't actually know of any documents stating the rationale) for the compiler to be allowed to recognize that the template definition you wrote is nonsensical and almost surely a mistake and to then refuse compiling the program containing it. What would be the point of writing your primary template this way?

However, from a language lawyer perspective IFNDR actually means that no requirements are placed on the compiler for handling the IFNDR program at all, so that it may also e.g. compile it to an executable with any arbitrary behavior. If the above rationale was intended, the standard could have been written to say specifically that whether or not the compilation will fail is unspecified.

If the goal is to provide some specific form of diagnostic if the primary template is instantiated although it never should be, or if the goal is to prevent a specialization to be silently considered incomplete, `static_assert(false, "message");` can be used. An exception to [[temp.res.general]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#8.1) has been added for an always-failing `static_assert` recently as a defect report via resolution of [CWG 2518](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2518.html) for this use case.

Comment: While that may be the point of the rule, the actual rule is far crueler.  IF,NDR means that the existence of the above template permits the compiler to modify the program behavior in arbitrary ways.  I suspect we might want to add wording that states that compilers are free to fail to compile and issue a diagnostic, or free to ignore the template, but not free to do arbitrary actions, in such cases.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes, I clarified that.

Comment: On the committee there has been talk about adding a new category of "unspeciformed" programs, but no one has written the paper yet, in part because no one can think of a good name.